# SAS Conditionally Call a Macro

Tags: if-statement, sas, macros, sas-macro

I have a macro called "checks" and I would like to only call it when a previously defined macro variable (called run_type)= model. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
%if &run_type. = 'Model' %then %do;
%checks;
%end;
```

But this doesn't work, can anyone help?

Comment: Do you get an error or simply a different result from what you expect?

Comment: It just didn't run at all but the answer from Tom below fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will work fine as long as the value of RUN_TYPE is literally `'Model'` complete with the mixed case and enclosing single quotes.

If instead the value of RUN_TYPE is just `Model` or perhaps even `model` or `MODEL` then you might want to use this comparison instead.

```
%if %qupcase(&run_type.) = MODEL %then %do;
%checks;
%end;
```

Answer (score 0):

When using conditional macros in SAS I tend to think of this as ‘all values are already strings’ (with the exception of % statements) so you do not need quotes. This is also true of parameters in macro function equivalents.

Conversely this is why numeric operations need the %eval for example.

This is obviously a huge oversimplification of what goes on in the macro processor.